# What is the timeframe used, for TCPBacklogDrop value calculation in netstat

Tags: linux, tcp, netstat

I'm interested in the value `TCPBacklogDrop` of the command `netstat -s` on linux. 
But I don't know which timeframe is considered, when calculating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791089/determine-average-transfer-rate-on-linux-system-ip-interface

> The counts are typically since the interface was created, which is usually boot time for "real" interfaces.